# Use local database in android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I am trying to develop an Android app. I use a local database "AndroidProject.db" which is put into the assets folder. When I try to copy the database to its correct location I encounter a NullPointer Exception. I marked the line where the Exception is happening.

Source Code:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int VERSION = 1;
public SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
private static final String TAG = "DBHelper";
public Context myContext;
public static final String DB_NAME = "AndroidProject.db";

public DBHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,VERSION);
}

public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void openDatabase() {
    importDatabase();
    Log.i(TAG, "open database");
}
    public void closeDatabase() {
    myDatabase.close();
    Log.i(TAG, "close database");
}

public void importDatabase() {
    File f = null;
    try {
        // Exception occurs here
        f = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!f.exists()) {
        try {
            f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            InputStream is = myContext.getAssets().open("AndroidProject.db");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(buffer);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("File Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    if (myDatabase == null || !myDatabase.isOpen()) {
        myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(f.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}

public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
    return myDatabase;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

The error is happening here: `f = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);`

Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at fu.android.example.travelvnproject_v01.Database.DBHelper.importDatabase(DBHelper.java:59)
at fu.android.example.travelvnproject_v01.Database.DBHelper.openDatabase(DBHelper.java:42)
at fu.android.example.travelvnproject_v01.Database.DBProvider.query(DBProvider.java:38)
at fu.android.example.travelvnproject_v01.LocalActivity.onCreate(LocalActivity.java:41)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
```

Comment: Pretty clear error - `myContext` must be null. Are you initializing it somewhere?

Comment: I just use 'myContext' one time.

Comment: You may use myContext just once, but you still have to initialize it. You say you implemented my suggested changes and there was still the same NullPointerException? I'm asking because that would be pretty much impossible. Please post the code with the changes from my answer and indicate on which exact line the error is happening.

Comment: I just tested your code and it is working fine with my changes. The only problem was that myContext was not set. If your are sure that even with my changes it is not working than there must be a problem somewhere else. I will edit the code I used into my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is happening because myContext is null. Try this:

```
public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);

    myContext = context;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I tested with this source code with my suggested changes and it's working fine, I only made a few other changes for convenience and I removed the unnecessary try/catch block:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    private static final String TAG = "DBHelper";
    public Context myContext;
    public static final String DB_NAME = "AndroidProject.db";

    public DBHelper(Context context){
        this(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION); // Changed this to call the other constructor for convinience
    }

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                    int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);

        myContext = context;
    }

    public void openDatabase() {
        importDatabase();
        Log.i(TAG, "open database");
    }
    public void closeDatabase() {
        myDatabase.close();
        Log.i(TAG, "close database");
    }

    public void importDatabase() {
        File f = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            try {
                f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                InputStream is = myContext.getAssets().open("AndroidProject.db");
                int size = is.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fos.write(buffer);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("File Error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (myDatabase == null || !myDatabase.isOpen()) {
            myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(f.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
        return myDatabase;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Well how does it not work? You are still getting a Null Pointer Exception? How about you post relevant logcat output.

Comment: 03-20 12:14:56.963:W/System.err(21859):java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 12:14:56.973: W/System.err(21859):atfu.android.example.travelvnproject_v01.Database.DBHelper.importDatabase(DBHelper.java:54)
03-20 12:14:56.973: W/System.err(21859):atfu.android.example.travelvnproject_v01.Database.DBHelper.openDatabase(DBHelper.java:42)

Comment: Please edit the logcat output into your question and edit in more of the logcat.

Comment: Thank you @Xaver Kappeller so much. My code is worked. And I show that you changed `super(context,DB_NAME,null,VERSION);` to `this(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);` in `public DBHelper(Context context)`. This error made me to spend a lot of time.